# While installing anaconda on raspberry pi 4 ( Debian ) i faced this error : conda.exe: no such file or directory while executing bash or even sh

Tags: raspberry-pi, anaconda, debian

While installing anaconda on raspberry pi 4 ( Debian )  i faced this error : conda.exe: no such file or directory while executing bash or even sh ( the file downloaded )
this error continues even with Mambaforge and Miniforge3

Answer (score 0):

This is due to usage of 32-bit Raspbian. The aarch64 packages of conda require a matching distro. You can confirm arch of your distro using `uname -m`. If it shows armv7*, you will need to move to 64 bit.